# Select dynamic DOM Elements in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw shapes and select and interact with them using D3. I am learning D3, so need to understand some logic more clearly. 
I can draw shapes, I need to drag them while selecting a shape. I cannot seem to select the particular object when there are multiple objects drawn on canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/nilarya/WKa8F/2/ this is where I have been so far, I request you to take a look at it,(the code is somewhat messy, I'm sorry, its late in here... :() if you draw multiple objects (Circles and/or Rectangles) on the canvas and then try to select one, you will notice the error.

I have tried using

```
d3.select(this)
```

and also

```
d3.select(this.firstChild)
```

but I need to select a particular circle or rectangle. how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `dragmove` listener to handle only the selected shape, i.e. the shape to which this listener is binded to.
All you'll have to do is assign the selection of `this` by D3 to a variable, and use that instead of the external references, like so:

```js
function dragmove(d) {
    var shape = d3.select(this);
    if (isrectMov == true) {
        shape.attr("x", d3.event.x)
            .attr("y", d3.event.y)
            .attr("cursor", "move");
    } else if (islineMov == true) {
        shape.attr("x1", d3.event.x)
            .attr("y1", d3.event.y)
            .attr("x2", d3.event.x)
            .attr("y2", d3.event.y)
            .attr("cursor", "move");
    } else if (iscircleMov == true) {
        shape.attr("cx", d3.event.x)
            .attr("cy", d3.event.y)
            .attr("cursor", "move");
    } else {}
}
```

However, this will work only for similar shapes, the code has some more issues that needs to be addressed. I suggest you start from scratch, and try not to use global variables at all, but instead require (or *select*) any shape when you need it (e.g. inside a handler). This will reduce complexity as you no longer have to try to follow the state of each variable in your minds eyes.

---

[<kbd><sub>[image: jsfiddle-icon]</sub> **Demo**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPIqU.png)

Comment: If I have drawn 2 circles and one rectangle, how do I know which circle to drag when I select with mouse down?

Comment: sorry, my bad. updating now